# Existe un modismo o expresión en español para "one-ups/one-upped"?

Tags: traducción, expresiones, solicitud-de-modismo

Hoy me ha dado por leer [esta noticia](http://www.msn.com/en-us/movies/celebrity/mark-wahlberg-demanded-to-meet-his-daughters-date-but-he-got-a-surprise/ar-BBCTrjO?li=BBnbfcL&ocid=mailsignout) *superchorra* que me salía al cerrar la cuenta de correo.

Básicamente, Mark Wahlberg (actor) le dice a su hija de 13 años que quiere conocer a su novio/cita, para saber si es un buen muchacho. Resulta que el chico se presenta en casa del actor, con su propia madre. La noticia dice

> So the prospective boyfriend comes over to the house. "And he **one-ups** me," said Wahlberg. "He brings his mom!"

[One-up](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/one-upping) es un modismo que significa "do better than (someone)." Podría traducirse como en la mayoría de los casos como `ganar`.

```
Person A: "I just got a 93% on my history test!" 
Person B: "I got a 98%." 
Person A: "Ok, you **one-upped** me there."
```

> Persona A: "Vale, [ahí] me has ganado.

Pero hay otros casos donde `ganar` no es la mejor opción (especialmente porque "ganar" también tiene el signficado de "conquistar", y podría entenderse como que alguien nos "convence" en lugar de que "lo hace mejor que nosotros"). En

> "He deftly one-upped the interrogator"

"One-upped" tiene el sentido de "ser más listo, más hábil, mejor, ir por delante".

Existe en español un modismo o expresión que tenga este sentido de "one-up someone"?

Comment: In English we use the verb to trump (in the sense of a card game, to take a trick by using a trump card = _palo de triunfo_) as a synonym, more or less. So how would you feel about _triunfar_ which seems about right?

Comment: Creo que en estos contextos usaría *superar*, pero a lo mejor ya has pensado en ello y no te ha gustado.

Comment: @guifa, no de hecho no caí en ese. Es genial! Esa sería la respuesta aceptada, es perfecto!

Comment: A ver si es que la madre del chico es fan de Mark Wahlberg y no quería dejar escapar la oportunidad... :-D

Answer (score 4):

Puedes usar la expresión «ganar por la mano»:

> [**ganar a alguien por la mano.**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=OF9CzGo%7COFAJXYy)
>   1. loc. verb. Anticipársele en hacer o lograr algo.

Usando tus ejemplos:

> Me ganó por la mano: ¡se trajo a su madre!
>
> Definitivamente ganó al interrogador por la mano.

Además, al ser figurativa te sirve también para casos más negativos o abstractos, como el ejemplo de GingerHead:

> Las cosas me están ganando por la mano últimamente.

Answer (score 2):

El significado cambia segun el contexto, por ejemplo:

> *One day, curiosity one-upped me.*
>   **Un día, la curiosidad me venció.**
>
> *Curiosity finally one-upped me this week.*
>   **Finalmente me ganó la curiosidad esta semana.**
>
> *Things have been one-upping me.*
>   **Las cosas me están derrotando.**

Entonces como he dicho anteriormente, segun el contexto los significados pueden variar entre:

> 1. Vencer
> 2. Ganar
> 3. Derrotar

Comment: Can an inanimate object engage in one upmanship?

Comment: @mdewey Y tanto, y todo pasa aleatoriamente. Las casualidades, no todo sucede por azar pero en este caso digamos que sí.

Comment: @Gorpik Gracias, muy amable